# Subdifferential of (A+B) = Subdifferential (A) + Subdifferential (B)

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

The equality holds if both A and B are convex. Does the quality still hold if A is continuous differentiable but nonconvex and B is convex? Or put any way, what additional conditions are needed on A if A is nonconvex, such that the equality still holds?

Comment: Take a look at [Corollary 10.9 of Rockafellar and Wets' Variational Analysis](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.

Comment: But, is the definition of subdifferential on page 301 the same as a typical definition: g is a subgradient if $f(x)-f(x_0) \geq g(x-x_0)$. In particular, is 8.8 part (b) correct? I don't see how it is correct.